# Python: Find the peaks of a signal

Tags: python, filter, signals

Im trying to find a method to filter data sets that looks almost like this

[image]

1. The blue is the original signal
2. The orange is filtered using average of batches
3. the green is the peaks using the `scipy.find_peaks`

**Some backgroud:**
The graph represents weight for two periods, i would like to find the circled points so i can tell in the first period the collected weight was X and in the second period it was Y.

The problem is my `find_peaks` paramters arent applicaple on each data set, so everytime i have to customize its parameters which dosent make any sense

I tried to calculate the slope but that didnt work out well.

Which method or algorithm would you use for such a problem?